# wordpress can't dequeue script/style that has query

Tags: wordpress

Not sure if I worded it correctly but basically I wanted to load plugin CSS/JS on pages only that uses the actual plugins.. I have gotten a lot of it done by search thru the plugin files for any handles used in `wp_enqueue_script` within the plugins and simply `wp_dequeue_script` them in functions.php

However, there are some enqueues for style that include a .php and not a css file, for example.. in the plugin it enqueues a file

```
wp_enqueue_style("myrp-stuff", MYRP_PLUGIN_URL . "/myrp-hotlink-css.php");
```

so I've tried:

```
wp_dequeue_style('myrp-stuff');
wp_deregister_style('myrp-stuff');
```

It doesn't work

However, when the page/post is rendered it shows as

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='myrp-stuff-css'  href='http://www.modernlogic.co/wp/wp-content/plugins/MyRP/myrp-hotlink-css.php?ver=3.4.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

It addes -css to the id and it refuses to dequeue/deregister and be moved.

I have also tried the following with no luck

```
wp_dequeue_style('myrp-stuff-css');
wp_deregister_style('myrp-stuff-css');
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Would love if someone could help me with this :-(

Answer (score 17):

Scripts and styles can be enqueued in any order and at anytime before `wp_print_*` actions are triggered. Which can make it difficult to remove them from the queue before output.

To make dequeue work consistently hook into into `wp_print_styles` or `wp_print_scripts` with a high priority, as this will remove the scripts and styles just before output.

For instance in your plugin loader code or template's `functions.php` file you could have a function and action hook like this:

```
function remove_assets() {
    wp_dequeue_style('myrp-stuff');
    wp_deregister_style('myrp-stuff');
}
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'remove_assets', PHP_INT_MAX );
```

Setting a high `priority` (third argument to `add_action`) when hooking into the action will help ensure that the callback `remove_assets` gets called *last*, just before scripts/styles are printed.

Note, while this technique is legitimate for *removing* scripts/styles it should't be used for *adding* assets. See this [Wordpress Core blog post](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2011/12/12/use-wp_enqueue_scripts-not-wp_print_styles-to-enqueue-scripts-and-styles-for-the-frontend/) for more info.

Comment: Woh, thanks leepowers, I've had issues with dequeuing scripts many a times... this really did the trick!

Comment: Solved problem for me as well. +1

Comment: I owe you a beer, @leepowers

Comment: Thanks ! I was stuck for a long time and then this solved my problem. Best way to remove css included by plugins .

Comment: I would like to add that you could use PHP's Predefined Constants: PHP_INT_MAX so that you would never need to put something yourself. This way you will always use the highest possible integer in the current PHP build.

Answer (score 8):

Just to be sure, have you placed your code inside a function called by an action like this?:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_function');
function dequeue_function() {
    wp_dequeue_style( array('myrp-stuff', 'myrp-stuff-css') );
    wp_deregister_style( array('myrp-stuff', 'myrp-stuff-css') );
}
```